# What is the best form element for multiple number inputs? (Days, Hours, Minutes)

Tags: forms, gui-design, ux-integration

The user will input the Days / Hours / Minutes.
Should it be 3 sliders, or 3 input fields, or something else?
The design is on on desktop and tablet.

Comment: Do you have some more context for this? What is the domain? What is the user trying to do? Is it part of a larger form? This forum works best when you bring your efforts so far to share, and describe the larger context and constraints you're working with...

Comment: It's in a form for a bill payment information. And the (days, hours, minutes) is for validity of the payment. I tried researching but I could not find the best practices for this particular element.

Comment: Are users entering in billing hours that they submit for payment? Are they using some hourly billing software to keep track of what they work? 'Days' is a vague concept in a workplace in some cases.

Comment: It's the number of days the bill will be valid for. I will suggest another approach like (selecting a date) that will be more clear. But i need to design the option of inputting days,hours,minutes.

Comment: Are hours and minutes equaly important as days input?

Comment: Actually i'm not sure if hours and minutes are equally important or not. I will have to look at analytics and user usage.

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to suggest this kind of selection. in the desktop mode it's easy to click and type as well as tablet mode it's easy to tap and select numbers. and I've put 5x to the minutes for more user-friendliness.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you i appreciate your effort. Do you suggest that the numbers stay visible? Keep in mind these are within a long form.

Comment: nope. with some nice animation, it's doesn't matter to keep. BTW it's up to you